# Polynom to linear factors above the complex numbers

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers

How do i find the linear factors from which the polynom:

$$
x^2+i
$$

Is built from.

I remember that every polynom above the complex can be represent as linear factors, but how do i do that in my example?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the square root of complex number i?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/664962/what-is-the-square-root-of-complex-number-i), resp. of $-i$.

Comment: The solution can be found also at many other places, e.g., [here](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-factorise-z-2+i), or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1268765/factor-z4-1-into-linear-factors).

Comment: Yes, thanks worked

Comment: But what answered was the quora and not the link to mathstack @Dietrich Burde

Comment: So have a look next time at quora, too. Just a remark, the answer here is the same as at quora.

Comment: What i meant is that he gave me a link to quora and that what helped, my question is referred to the wrong place. @Dietrich Burde

Comment: No, it is not. It says "so the square roots of $i$ are $\pm\left(\frac1{\sqrt{2}}+\frac1{\sqrt{2}}i\right)$, which just gives the linear factors you want.

Comment: Ah, I see. I forgot to say that $x^2+i=(x+\sqrt{i})(x-\sqrt{i})$ by the binomial formula. Then it should be clear that it is the same.